# How to calculate the variance

Tags: variance, covariance, standard-deviation, beta-function

So i have this question and I wanted to be sure that my calculations were correct.

> The standard deviations of the market returns is $0.2(20%)$ and the
>   covariance between the return on the market portfolio and Amazon is
>   $0.05$. Calculate the beta of Amazon.

So i know that Beta= (covariance)/ variance, where

- Covariance=Measure of a stock’s return relative to that of the market,
- Variance=Measure of how the market moves relative to its mean.

Then am I correct by squaring the Standard deviation of the market returns ($0.2$ times $0.2$) to get $0.04$ as the variance and then the Beta would be $0.05/0.04$?

Is my answer right?
​